# grouping values in a list of tuples to a dictionary

Tags: python

I've a list of tuples (comes in pairs only)

```
a = [(1,2),(1,4),(3,5),(5,7)]
```

which I'm trying to convert to a dictionary as below

```
d = {1: [2, 4], 3: 5, 5: 7}
```

Here's what I've come up with -

```
a= [(1,2),(1,4),(3,5),(5,7)]
d= {}

for k, v in a:
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = v
    else:
        d[k] = [d[k]]
        d[k].append(v)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can this be achieved using something like `defaultdict(list)` without having to compromise on the desired output?

Comment: It's hard to review this without knowing more about the context. What are you going to use this data structure for? What would go wrong if you used `{1: [2, 4], 3: [5], 5: [7]}` instead?

Comment: thanks @GarethRees! only few values repeat, say 1 in 100. So, is it worth using the data structure as you suggested?

Comment: How can I tell? You have to explain the purpose of the code, before I can tell you what data structure would best meet that purpose.

Comment: @GarethRees the keys are places and the values their area codes. I've to fetch the code based on the place and vice versa. In rare cases, places have two codes. hope it's clear to you!

Comment: This is example code, and so is off-topic here. We can't really review something if we don't know what it is... Please include your actual code in future, or if this question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a builtin that solves your problem, but there is an even simpler solution than the one you provided. Taking Gareth Rees' comment into consideration, I would solve your problem like this:

```
input_list = [(1,2),(1,4),(3,5),(5,7)]
output_dict = {}

for key, value in input_list:
    #Initialize empty list if key doesn't exist
    if key not in output_dict:
        output_dict[key] = []
    # Now we know that the key always exists
    output_dict[key].append(value)

print(output_dict)
# If you want single items to be integers instead of lists
for key, value in output_dict.items():
    if len(value) == 1:
        output_dict[key] = value[0]

print(output_dict)
```

Output:

```
{1: [2, 4], 3: [5], 5: [7]}
{1: [2, 4], 3: 5, 5: 7}
```

The first for loop creates a dictionary mapping ints to lists. The advantages of this structure compared to the solution you provided is that there are no type-checks required when parsing the data. Checking if a value is a duplicate is a simple `if len(value) > 1`.

Usually, I'd prefer this implementation in any application that is not extremely dependent on performance. If your application requires a lot of performance, I'd suggest:

1. Not using Python
2. Not using dicts

If this is the case, I could elaborate on more ways of improving performance.

In the more likely scenario that a coherent data structure is more important, I'd reduce your code to the first for-loop above, and wrapping it in a function:

```
def list_to_dict(input_list):
    output_dict = {}
    for key, value in input_list:
        if key not in output_dict:
            output_dict[key] = []
        output_dict[key].append(value)
    return output_dict
```

Comment: thanks @maxb! you've two for loops. how does that make it simpler?

Comment: It depends on if you want to use arrays for single items, or if you want to use integers. By using arrays for single items, you'll avoid doing something like `if type(value) == int`, which is probably better in the long run. If you really want to go with different data types in the dict, I'd use your original solution.

Comment: On Code Review you need to describe one improvement, dumping code is not allowed here. I also don't see why you wouldn't use a dictionary comprehension instead...

Comment: @Peilonrayz I'd say that avoiding `if type(value) == int` constitutes an improvement. I'm not sure how such a comprehension would be implemented. One could write `output_dict = {key: value for (key, value) in input_list}`, but it wouldn't handle the duplicate cases.

Comment: @maxb As I said before "On Code Review you need to ___describe___ one improvement, dumping code is not allowed here." You havn't described any improvements and the code is just a code dump.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Fair point, I have edited the post to change this.